# Converting nested list to pandas dataframe with column names

Tags: python, pandas, data-processing

[Image of Original DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQpx9.png)

I have a nested list that looks something like this.

```
features = 
[['0:0.084556', '1:0.138594', '2:0.094304\n'],
 ['0:0.101468', '4:0.138594', '5:0.377215\n'],
 ['0:0.135290', '2:0.277187', '3:0.141456\n']
]
```

Each list within the nested list is a row that is comma separated. The left side of the ":" is the column name and the right side is the row value.

I want to transform this to a pandas data frame to look like this:

```
  f_0000  |  f_0001  |  f_0002  |  f_0003  |  f_0004  | f_0005
---------------------------------------------------------------
 0.084556 | 0.138594 | 0.094304 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000
 0.101468 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.138594 | 0.377215
 0.135290 | 0.000000 | 0.277187 | 0.141456 | 0.000000 | 0.000000
```

Can someone help me out on how to do this?

Original DF (it doesn't format correctly on pd.read_clipboard for me however..)

```
    ex_id   labels  features
0   0   446,521,1149,1249,1265,1482 0:0.084556 1:0.138594 2:0.094304 3:0.195764 4:...
1   1   78,80,85,86 0:0.050734 1:0.762265 2:0.754431 3:0.065255 4:...
2   2   457,577,579,640,939,1158    0:0.101468 1:0.138594 2:0.377215 3:0.130509 4:...
3   3   172,654,693,1704    0:0.186024 1:0.346484 2:0.141456 3:0.195764 4:...
4   4   403,508,1017,1052,1731,3183 0:0.135290 1:0.277187 2:0.141456 3:0.065255 4:...
```

Comment: Are those strings in the list? Or is this some "list" in a text file?

Comment: This was originally a dataframe that had all items in the list as a single column. I did `list(train['features'].str.split(' '))` to convert it to the nested list.

Comment: features = 
[[0:0.084556, 1:0.138594, 2:0.094304\n],
 [0:0.101468, 4:0.138594, 5:0.377215\n],
 [0:0.135290, 2:0.277187, 3:0.141456\n]
]
This is not a proper list can you send the actual list.

Comment: @SachinGupta updated apologies about that.

Comment: can you add a sample of the original dataframe? may be quicker to take it from there.

Comment: @Mit added image of original DF. It's the features column I am trying to output as multiple columns based on the ID before the ":".

Comment: ok now i get what you're trying to do, let me see if i can write a script real quick

Comment: @Eisen Don't post picture. Just copy and paste it here so that people don't have to create a dataframe. We will be able to use your dataframe by using `pd.read_clipboard()`  . So please post your dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simple will remain `for` loops.

1. First, select all keys from the given `features`.

   1. For all elements, we use [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) and extract the first element.
   2. Then, because we only want unique keys, we use [`set`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html). Then, we convert it back to `list` and sort the keys using `sorted` ([here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) some details if needed).

The first is sum up in:

```
keys = sorted(list(set([elt.split(':')[0] for l in features for elt in l])))
```

2. Create an empty `dict` from the above keys and initialize all keys with an empty list:

```
data = {k:[] for k in keys}
```

3. Iterate over all the features:

   1. Save all the key features visited in a `seen` variable
   2. Add all featured keys and values
   3. Complete the data with keys not in the current `features`
4. Eventually, create the dataframe from out dict using the default constructor [`pd.DataFrame()`] (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html).
5. Correctly format columns name using [`.columns`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.columns.html) and string formatting ([`format`](https://docs.python.org/fr/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#the-string-format-method)). [Here](https://pyformat.info/) are some good explanations.

---

Talked enough, here the **full code + illustration**:

```
features = [["0:0.084556", "1:0.138594", "2:0.094304"],
    ["0:0.101468", "4:0.138594", "5:0.377215"],
    ["0:0.135290", "2:0.277187", "3:0.141456"]
    ]

# Step 1
keys = sorted(list(set([elt.split(':')[0] for l in features for elt in l])))
print(keys)
# ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5']

# Step 2
data = {k:[] for k in keys}
print(data)
# {'0': [], '1': [], '2': [], '3': [], '4': [], '5': []}

# Step 3
for sub in features:
    # Step 3.1
    seen = []
    # Step 3.2
    for l in sub:
        k2, v = l.split(":")        # Get key and value
        data[k2].append(float(v))   # Append current value to data
        seen.append(k2)             # Set the key as seen

    # Step 3.3
    for k in keys:                  # For all data keys
        if k not in seen:           # If not seen
            data[k].append(0)       # Add 0

print(data)
# {'0': [0.084556, 0.101468, 0.13529], 
#     '1': [0.138594, 0, 0], 
#     '2': [0.094304, 0,0.277187],
#     '3': [0, 0, 0.141456],
#     '4': [0, 0.138594, 0],
#     '5': [0, 0.377215, 0]
# }

# Step 4
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
#           0         1         2         3         4         5
# 0  0.084556  0.138594  0.094304  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
# 1  0.101468  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.138594  0.377215
# 2  0.135290  0.000000  0.277187  0.141456  0.000000  0.000000

# Step 5
df.columns = ["f_{:04d}".format(int(val)) for val in df.columns]
print(df)
#      f_0000    f_0001    f_0002    f_0003    f_0004    f_0005
# 0  0.084556  0.138594  0.094304  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
# 1  0.101468  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.138594  0.377215
# 2  0.135290  0.000000  0.277187  0.141456  0.000000  0.000000
```

Comment: well done, very clean approach!  i was trying to do something similar but my python skills failed me again!

Comment: This is awesome! If I have number a column such as "f_1000", the columns would not be in order anymore, no?

Comment: What let you think that ? Columns are sorted at step 1

Comment: for example if I had 5000 features. column f_0000 would be first, then f_0001, then f_0010. should be column f_0000, then f_0001, then f_0002. However, I can probably figure that part out. Thanks!!

Comment: Great ! An alternative is to convert to number, sort and then back to string (if needed..) :-)

Answer (score -2):

try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Column name 1'], ['column name 2'])
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.